# How does Backbone's events context work?

Tags: backbone.js

I'm learning backbone from the docs, can you provide an example of how the context works for Events? I don't really understand what they mean by the below:

> To supply a context value for this when the callback is invoked, pass
>   the optional last argument: model.on('change', this.render, this) or
>   model.on({change: this.render}, this).

Answer (score 3):

This is the event listeners.

For example,

```
model.on('change', this.render, this)
```

The first parameter is the event type: For example in this case, "change" if event has happened.

The second parameter is the function which you want to call. Let's say if a model has changed, call this function.

Third is the context. ('this') represents the context that you're clicking. For example if you are clicking in an input box, this.$el will be input box. If you don't mention this. Your 'this' will be window object.

**For example:**

```
var SomeModelView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
  },
  render: function() {
    // render a template
    console.log("Template Rendered");
  }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8AH3t/169/

**Warning:**

It's always recommended to use this.listenTo instead of using this.model.on.

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
```

**Why?**

> When calling the .remove() method, the "change" event handler (our
>   render function) is still bound. So while the DOM element may be
>   removed, the view object itself is never released from memory.

**Source:** http://ozkatz.github.io/avoiding-common-backbonejs-pitfalls.html

Comment: you should `console.log(this);` in that example... I think that is what OP doesn't understand

Comment: yeah what would this console log to? what is the point of adding that as context, wouldn't it still work without it?

Comment: @jlei i've added the response. Basically 'this' is the scope/context. Please check the jsfiddle I attached. If you are clicking an input box, this will be the scope for that input box. And this.$el will be the ID/Class for that box.